# How to create foreign keys in gorm?

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

So I have two tables in application: `users` and `posts`. I'd like to implement a liking functionality where a user can like a post. To do this I created the following table:

```
type Like struct {
    PostId    string    `json:"post_id"`
    UserId    string    `json:"user_id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
}
```

**My questions is** how can I make it so when I `AutoMigrate` the `Like` model, foreign keys are setup automatically?

**I have tried** using the `gorm:"foreignKey:Post"` and `gorm:"foreignKey:User"` struct tags in their respective spots but they don't do anything.

How could I get this to work? Thank you!

Comment: Have you used gorm.Model in User and Post struct? Please share the User and Post struct.

Answer (score 4):

As you are not following conventions (i.e. Id instead of ID, PostId instead of PostID) in naming you need to explicitly tell gorm which is the foreign key and referred to which property.

Here is the snippet. [Github Link](https://github.com/Shahriar-Sazid/go-random-test/blob/master/storage2/gorm5.go)

Reference:

1. [Belongs To](https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html)
2. [Has Many](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html)

```
package storage2

import (
    "log"

    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/logger"
)

type Post struct {
    Body   string `gorm:"type:text"`
    Id     string `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key"`
    Likes  []Like `gorm:"foreignkey:PostId;references:Id"`
    User   User   `gorm:"foreignkey:UserId;references:Id"`
    UserId string
}

type Like struct {
    Id     string `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key"`
    PostId string `gorm:"type:uuid;not null"`
    User   User   `gorm:"foreignkey:UserId;references:Id"`
    UserId string
}

type User struct {
    Id   string `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key"`
    Name string
}

func GormTest() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("gorm.db"), &gorm.Config{
        Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info),
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("could not open database")
    }
    err = db.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &Post{}, &Like{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("could not migrate database")
    }
    createTestData(db)
    fetchData(db)
}

func createTestData(db *gorm.DB) {
    users := []User{
        {Id: "0b83313d-1f85-4093-8621-efd2f21419d3", Name: "Shahriar"},
        {Id: "bddd6566-bcd2-4ad1-8eb9-65a23f5a9856", Name: "John"},
        {Id: "663c1328-dce2-4527-aecb-7fc478c229c2", Name: "Durand"}}
    err := db.Create(&users).Error
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("failed to create user data")
    }
    like := Like{
        Id:     "45ba45fc-0900-4fcc-80dd-c394170b777b",
        UserId: users[0].Id,
    }
    post := Post{
        Id:     "4cebb4c7-d44e-4160-a2df-a06f43211d45",
        Body:   "Test Post",
        Likes:  []Like{like},
        UserId: users[1].Id,
    }
    err = db.Create(&post).Error
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("failed to crete post")
    }
}

func fetchData(db *gorm.DB) {
    post := Post{
        Id: "4cebb4c7-d44e-4160-a2df-a06f43211d45",
    }
    if err := db.Preload("Likes").First(&post).Error; err != nil {
        log.Println("failed to load post")
    }
    log.Println(post)
}
```